# How do I access scripts outside of my root directory?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have another question up about this but I thought it might be best to create a new question to get more detailed with this second issue.

I am on an Shared Hosting account and its an Apache server.

I have some backend scripts that I want to protect from being accessed directly via the url. For example I do not want someone to be able to go to mysite.com/php/cms/addEditors.php as I fear there could be some security issues. So to do this I have created a new root directory. My structure looks something like this

```
Public
| index.php
| Login.php
| EditorHome.php
Src
| CMS
| | loginProcess.php
| | logoutProcess.php
| | addEditors.php
```

To do this I have an .htaccess page  in the same directory as the Public and Src directories that has these 2 lines that make the Public directory my root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^$ /Public [L]
```

The problem that I am having is when I put in the login details and submit I get an 404 Error that says:

***The requested URL /Src/CMS/loginProcess.php was not found on this server.***

even though the code that directs it to the loginProcess looks like this

**../Src/CMS/loginProcess.php**

Also, is there a way to remove /Public/ from being in the URL with .htaccess? I would prefer it be

***mysite.com/login.php***

rather than

***mysite.com/Public/login.php***

Comment: Normally the root folder _is_ the public folder - so the files in your Public folder and the src folder should be one dir up. In order to navigate to files outside the root folder you need to route them through a file in the public directory. Many frameworks (Symfony, Laravel, etc) do this by routing all requests through index.php

Comment: Yea had that set up except I wanted to prevent the Src folder from being access directly using the url. To fix this I created the new root and placed the backend code outside of that one. Maybe I have a misunderstanding as well. I am using PDO and prepared statements so is there any harm in someone going to mysite.com/php/cms/addEditors.php directly? When I go there directly I receive errors but I am unsure if this is safe. Also, I want to avoid any frameworks just so I can learn more about all of this.

Comment: Moving src files out of the public dir is mostly to organize code / keep a project structure. What you _can_ risk is that some change/update on your host breaks the apache config/PHP leading to PHP not parsing your files. If I then access `/src/config.php` or similar your config details (db credentials etc) would leak.

Comment: If you're able to add files outside of the public_html dir on your host then normally your src folder would be at the same level as that public dir. If you're not able to add files outside of the public dir I wouldn't bother (or change host)

Comment: @JimL I feel like it is an issue with the ftp/subdomain communication, but as of yet I have not figure out how to add anything in the same directory as my public_html. I am not sure if its because I am using a subdomain and the ftp doesn't have permission, but when trying to access any of it from the main ftp account I don't see any of my sub domain files. So I am unsure where to place them there.

Comment: @JimL is it safe to assume that I am over complicating things? Does the PDO/prepared statements prevent the addEditor.php script from being used maliciously? My biggest weakness as far as web dev is concerned is security. I am unsure what I should be protecting and what is safe.

Comment: Using parameterized queries safe guards against SQL injection, meaning someone can't run malicious SQL commands with your SQL user (dumping data, etc).

Comment: @JimL Yeah, the more I got to thinking about it the more that made sense. I think its my lack of understanding with security measures that makes me so paranoid. Im all self taught, and this type of thing is something I am always unsure of. Do I need to have this question closed, or do anything?

Comment: Don't build your own CMS.  It's been done.  Go to cmsmatrix.org and choose one that meets your requirements.

Comment: @user2182349 There are no requirements, except for me to learn new things. Its a learning project and I'd like to go without a framework or any pre-built method. Once I understand things I wouldn't mind using something pre-built, but for now its more about getting a better grasp on things.

Comment: @Vaprx - You are more than likely running your shared hosting on cPanel. If that is correct, then create your subdomain and point it to something like `/subdomains/yoursubdomain/public_html` and then place your `src` directory inside `yoursubdomain`. Then use `.htaccess` to route everything to an `index.php` file in `public_html` - this file should `require` the files in your `src` directory. For reference, PDO and prepared statements is a good step towards better security, but it is not enough - the aim is to make your application 'bulletproof', as it were.

Comment: @MikeRockett Thanks for the info, trying to avoid turning this into a conversation, The project I am working on at the moment is already in a subdomain, and I can't place/alter anything outside of the public_html folder. I am off tomorrow and plan to call and discuss this issue with my host. It is probably something I am doing wrong, but we will see. Security is a huge concern for me, but has been difficult for me to wrap my head around.

Comment: @Vaprx - If `Public` and `Src` are inside `public_html`, try see if your host can point the subdomain to the `Public` folder. Then do the `index.php` thing I explained before.